# Getting the correct road bike size, moving from MTB

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit, size

Currently I have a [Large Stumpjumper 2021 29er](https://www.specializedconceptstore.co.uk/product/16347/2020-stumpjumper-st-alloy-29/).

The size was advised by the shop I purchased it from. It was OK at first but I ended up having a bike fit to adjust a few things (slightly longer stem and get the saddle height/position dialed in) which helped a lot.

I am now looking at getting a [Canyon CF 7.0](https://www.canyon.com/en-gb/road-bikes/endurance-bikes/endurace/endurace-cf-sl-7-disc/2947.html).

The fitter is advising me to get a Large (based on measurements below),
however Canyon are advising to go with a medium.

My height is close to 180cm and 80cm inside seam.

Its not that I don't agree the fitter might be correct, it's just Canyon say the bike would be bike and I am not sure the best course of action or the differences I would feel going from the MTB to either sized road bike.
As its direct to consumer I am wary about purchasing a bike too large.

I've tried to look at the Geometry comparison on [99spokes.com](https://99spokes.com/compare?bikes=specialized-stumpjumper-alloy-2021;*z.S4%7Cw.29,canyon-endurace-cf-sl-disc-7.0-2021) / [geometrygeeks.bike](https://geometrygeeks.bike/compare/specialized-stumpjumper-st-alloy-29-2020-l,canyon-endurace-cf-sl-7-disc-2021-m,canyon-endurace-cf-sl-7-disc-2021-l/) and while I can see the size differences I am not too sure what it would mean in real terms.

Fitter provided these measurements:

[image]

I do realize the main advice I'll get here is

1. I should discuss further with the fitter (I 100% will, just not
   available at the moment)
2. Get a bike that I can test ride. (Wasn't possible with Canyon and no local stock of similar bikes or alternatives to try)

But I wanted to ask here if anyone's had any similar experiences with MTB to road or Larger bike than manufacturers suggested.
Or any general thoughts on it.

Comment: Why is the MTB relevant here at all?

Comment: Just based on height, M sounds reasonable. I agree that buying road bike without trying is a bad idea if you don't know your size, especially with Canyon because they have unusually short top tubes

Comment: If you really have only 80cm inseam but are 1.8m tall you might need the large size to get a long enough frame. Otherwise for your size I think medium would usually be right. I think it’s also better to have a slightly smaller frame rather than larger.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael yeah longer torso I guess :) but that makes sense too why a large is being recommended

Comment: If you have a long torso, you'll probably need to buy something that's not Canyon. The bike in the drawing has handlebars unusually high and no room for lowering them, how did you end up with that position?